# Error: The "token" value can only be set if the "firebaseUserAdminSDK" property is defined

Tags: firebase

When attempting to run my website with firebase locally I receive this error, which I haven't found anywhere on the web. The error occured after I configured some stuff for the live version (which works like a charm), but I simply have no idea what firebaseUserAdminSDK is or how to set the property.

My GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is set to a service account which should have all the necessary permissions via a .env file. I'm using the same SA, .env and code as the rest of my team, and only I am receiving this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I was an idiot, deleting cookies fixed it for me.